# Split a string only by the first element in golang

Tags: go, split, slice

I'm trying to parse git branch names and split them so I can seperate the remote and the branch name

Previously I just split on the first slash:

```
func ParseBranchname(branchString string) (remote, branchname string) {
    branchArray := strings.Split(branchString, "/")
    remote = branchArray[0]
    branchname = branchArray[1]
    return
}
```

But I forgot that some folks use slashes in git branch names as well, multiple even!

Right now I'm taking the first element in the slice from the split, then moving every element one done and merging back on the slash:

```
func ParseBranchname(branchString string) (remote, branchname string) {
    branchArray := strings.Split(branchString, "/")
    remote = branchArray[0]

    copy(branchArray[0:], branchArray[0+1:])
    branchArray[len(branchArray)-1] = ""
    branchArray = branchArray[:len(branchArray)-1]

    branchname = strings.Join(branchArray, "/")
    return
}
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

For Go >= 1.18 see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71542449/119527).

---

For Go < 1.18:

Use [`strings.SplitN`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#SplitN) with `n=2` to limit the result to two substrings.

```
func ParseBranchname(branchString string) (remote, branchname string) {
    branchArray := strings.SplitN(branchString, "/", 2)
    remote = branchArray[0]
    branchname = branchArray[1]
    return
}
```

Comment: Ah, I had tried this but misunderstood the N argument and tried with 0 and 1, now I understand it's not index bound, it's how many results you want to return! This works perfectly, thanks! :)

Comment: Yes, I too was confused, coming from Python where `str. split()` takes an optional `maxsplit` argument indicating the max number of times to *split*, not the max number of strings to return.

Answer (score 8):

#### Go 1.18

Use [`strings.Cut`](https://pkg.go.dev/strings#Cut):

> [This function] slices `s` **around the first instance of `sep`**, returning the text before and after `sep`. The `found` result reports whether `sep` appears in `s`. If `sep` does not appear in `s`, cut returns `s, "", false`.

```
func ParseBranchname(branchString string) (remote, branchname string) {
    remote, branchname, _ = strings.Cut(branchString, "/")
    return
}
```

(Note that this code snippet is ignoring the third return value, a boolean, that tells whether the separator was found in the input string or not.)

As mentioned in Go 1.18 release notes, `Cut` *"can replace and simplify many common uses of `Index`, `IndexByte`, `IndexRune`, and `SplitN`"*. In particular, `SplitN` with `n=2`.

Playground — originally posted by @mkopriva in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60774467/split-a-string-only-by-the-first-element-in-golang/71542449#comment107526502_60774467) — modified to include an example with `Cut`: https://go.dev/play/p/bjBhnr3Hg5O

Answer (score 1):

Use strings.Index to find the index of the first / and you split manually with that information:

```
func ParseBranchnameNew(branchString string) (remote, branchName string) {
        firstSlash := strings.Index(branchString, "/")
        remote = branchString[:firstSlash]
        branchName = branchString[firstSlash+1:]
        return
}
```

Comparing to your original code:

```
goos: linux
goarch: amd64
BenchmarkParseBranchname-12         10000000           131 ns/op
BenchmarkParseBranchnameNew-12      300000000            5.56 ns/op
PASS
```

Comment: how dd you benchmarked the method performance? Please give some info

Comment: Yes, `SplitN` will do one extra allocation, which may be needed anyway in a non-simplified version, otherwise the logic is the same as `SplitN` except this isn't validating the return of `Index`. ~100ns isn't even noise around the network calls in the context of the OP use case.

Comment: @AmitUpadhyay please read this for more details on how to benchmark: https://dave.cheney.net/2013/06/30/how-to-write-benchmarks-in-go

Answer (score 1):

One more way could be:

```
branchArray := strings.Split(branchString, "/")
branchArray = []string{branchArray[0], strings.Join(branchArray[1:], "/")}

remote = branchArray[0]
branchname = branchArray[1]
```